# JavaScript - Checkbox to enable/disable radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, radio-button

IM SO CLOSE!
by default, the buttons are enabled. also when checked both are enabled but when unchecked only one is disabled.

I want it so that when the check box is checked both radio buttons are enabled. and when unchecked both radio buttons are disabled.

no Jquery, please

JS:

```
var sipch = document.querySelector("input[name=sip]");
sipch.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
        document.querySelector("input[name=protocol]").removeAttribute("disabled");
    } else {
        document.querySelector("input[name=protocol]").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <form id="myForm" onsubmit="goPVFive(event)" method="get">
            <div id="pBFContainer" class="container">
                <div id="bodyFOption1">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="sip" value="true">Would you like to include establishing the SIP session test?<p>
                    <input type="radio" class="testD" name="protocol" value="udp" disable/>UDP
                    <input type="radio" class="testD" name="protocol" value="tcp" disable/>TCP <label class="testD">(UDP is most Common)</label>
                </div>
                <div id="bodyFOption2">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="fWallInt" value="true">Would you include SIP ALG firewall interference test"
                    </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" id="subButton" value="Next..." />
        </form>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="evalportalp1.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo need to use querySelectorAll and then loop through the results, disabling/enabling each of them:

```
  if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[name=protocol]')
        .forEach((elem) => elem.removeAttribute('disabled'));
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[name=protocol]')
        .forEach((elem) => elem.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'));
  }
```

Comment: this is going to a 2nd page and using the same JS file. is there a simple way to segment this eventListener to this specific page?

Comment: You should not load the js code that you are not using on the second page. Just split it into separate files

Comment: But if you want, of course, you can add a class to the inputs on the first page and adjust querySelector to look for this class (that is present only on the first page). Don't do it this way, the code will become unmaintainable very soon. So, just split the code:)